# Cannot link library when compiling with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

My directory structure is:

```
── bin
│   ├── mylib-osx.so.1.72
│   ├── mylib.so.1.72
├── my.c
```

I am trying to compile `my.c` and link `mylib-osx.so.1.72` (I'm on a macOS), but to no avail:

```
ld: library not found for -l:PhotoDNAx64.so.1.72
```

I tried:

- `gcc -o my -lmylib-osx my.c`
- `gcc -o my -lmylib-osx.so.1.72 my.c`
- `gcc -o my -lmylib my.c`
- `gcc -o my -L./bin -lmylib-osx my.c`
- `gcc -o my -L./bin -l:"mylib-osx.so.1.72" my.c`

What am I doing wrong and why cannot the library be found?

Comment: Read the documentation of MacOSX linker (probably of the `ld` program)

Answer (score -1):

> What am I doing wrong and why cannot the library be found?

Read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). **You was wrong in not reading that** (or any other documentation of `gcc`).

**Order of program arguments to `gcc` matters a lot** (and in practice several arguments are very useful, e.g. both `-Wall` and `-g` at least, and probably `-v` sometimes). You want something like

```
gcc -v -Wall -g my.c -lmylib-osx -o my
```

(also try variants of that), since `gcc` is running some `ld` or equivalent [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) command, and if you want to pass some `-L`*lib-directory* use something like

```
gcc -v -Wall -g my.c  -L./bin -lmylib-osx -o my
```

and you also need to read the documentation of MacOSX [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) (probably named  `ld`). You could also read Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book.

If you are not happy with `gcc` (but please use a recent version, so [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) in 2019, not the crappy software sold by Apple named `gcc`) consider using [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) (a recent version too, e.g. Clang 8 in 2019). It has the same limitation regarding order of program arguments than `gcc` does (since order of program arguments even mattered for Unix or POSIX [`cc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers)).

In general, **read the documentation of a command before asking questions** here about that command. A minima, `man gcc` on your Apple (or Linux) computer.

PS. The last time I have used some MacOSX was in 2004. My biased recommendation is to install and use Linux (which I use since 1993; I tried MacOSX around 2004 during less than a year, and have been disappointed both by the [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/), including its [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) and GUI [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment), and by the Apple hardware).

Comment: I've tried various combinations and to no avail. What do I need to read about linkers in this case? Obviously the whole book is not an option; same with changing the OS.

Comment: You need to read the documentation of  `gcc`  and of `ld`, because `gcc` is invoking `ld`